# When did the subjonctif imparfait/passé simple turn into literary tenses?

Tags: histoire, subjonctif, imparfait, évolution, passé-simple

I was wondering when exactly the "subjonctif imparfait" (and passé simple) fell out of (spoken) use, since they are still very much alive in other Romance languages. I had a look through a few grammars but I have never seen any dates mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Did some more research and found answers to my question:

- *passé simple*: [Why is the passé simple not used in spoken French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8208/why-is-the-pass%C3%A9-simple-not-used-in-spoken-french) lead me to [Disparition du passé simple en français oral (pdf)](https://tampub.uta.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/78483/gradu02171.pdf) which mentions early 19th century:

> Le passé simple n’est plus un temps de la langue parlée. Selon Meillet (1948 : 151) cette forme n’existe plus dans l’usage parlé depuis le début du 19e siècle.

- *subjonctif imparfait*: the [French Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif_imparfait_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Recul_et_disparition) says the disappearance started in the 18th century and carried through to early 19th century:

> Dès le XVIIIe siècle, le subjonctif imparfait tendait à disparaître dans la langue courante. [...] Cependant, son usage a considérablement reculé depuis le début du XIXe siècle

As for reasons, both articles mention phonetic shifts in the language itself and the homophony of certain forms (e.g. *fut* / *fût*, *alla* / *allât* etc.)